# Arduino Balance library error

Tags: c++, arduino

I have been trying to compile and fix this library from Github that will allow someone to create their own scale; however when I try to compile it for the arduino I get this error.

> Arduino: 1.6.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328"
>
> C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Q2-Balance-Arduino-Library\examples\hx711_two_cell\hx711_two_cell.ino:
>   In function 'void loop()':
>
> hx711_two_cell:40: error: no matching function for call to
>   'Q2Balance::tare(int)'
>
> ```
>  balance.tare(100);
>
>                  ^
> ```
>
> C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Q2-Balance-Arduino-Library\examples\hx711_two_cell\hx711_two_cell.ino:40:21:
>   note: candidate is:
>
> In file included from
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\Q2-Balance-Arduino-Library\examples\hx711_two_cell\hx711_two_cell.ino:1:0:
>
> C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Q2-Balance-Arduino-Library-master\src/Q2Balance.h:64:10:
>   note: void Q2Balance::tare(long int, void (*)())
>
> ```
>  void tare(long milliseconds, void (*afterTared)(void));
> ```

<s>I'm confused as to why there needs to be this second void argument</s> (Right, call back function)

I'm unsure what I need to change about this function in order to get this to compile
This is the .h file:

```
#ifndef q2balance_h
#define q2balance_h
#include "Arduino.h"

#define Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT 10
// #define Q2BALANCE_DEBUG

#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_GRAM 0
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_POUND 1
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_OUNCE 2
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_GRAIN 3
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_TROY 4
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_PWT 5
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_CARAT 6
#define Q2BALANCE_UNIT_NEWTON 7

struct BalanceCalibrationStruct {
  long calibrationZero;
  long calibrationMV[Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT];
  long calibrationMeasured[Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT];
  float calibrationScaler[Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT];
};

class Q2Balance
{
  private:
    BalanceCalibrationStruct _settings;
    bool _tared = false;
    bool _taring = false;
    bool _calibrating = false;
    bool _calibratingZero = false;
    bool _settling = false;
    long _smoothValue = 0;
    long _rawValue = 0;
    long _tareValue = 0;
    unsigned long _settleTimeout;
    long _settleMinVal = 0;
    long _settleMaxVal = 0;
    long _jitter = 0;
    int _calibrationIndex;
    void (*_afterCalibrated)(void);
    void sortCalibrations();
    int findCalibrationWindow(long voltage);
    float calcValue(int units, long value);
  public:
    long TARELIMIT = 110;
    long JUMPLIMIT = 200;
    long SAMPLE_COUNT = 10;
    bool LOGGING = false;
    Q2Balance();
    virtual ~Q2Balance();
    bool taring();
    bool tared();
    bool settling();
    bool calibrating();
    float adjustedValue(int units);
    float adjustedRawValue(int units);
    long smoothValue();
    long rawValue();
    long jitter();
    void calibrateZero(long milliseconds, void (*afterCalibrated)(void));
    void calibrate(int index, long measurement, long milliseconds, void (*afterCalibrated)(void));
    void measure(long measurement);
    void tare(long milliseconds, void (*afterTared)(void));
    long settle(long milliseconds);
    BalanceCalibrationStruct getCalibration();
    void setCalibration(BalanceCalibrationStruct newSettings);
    void tick();
    void printCalibration(int index);
    void printCalibrations();
};

#endif /* q2balance_h */
```

and the cpp file

```
#include "q2balance.h"

Q2Balance::Q2Balance(){
  _settings.calibrationZero = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT;i++)
  {
    _settings.calibrationMV[i]= 0;
    _settings.calibrationMeasured[i] = 0;
    _settings.calibrationScaler[i] = 0;
  }
}

Q2Balance::~Q2Balance(){
}

BalanceCalibrationStruct Q2Balance::getCalibration(){
  BalanceCalibrationStruct newSettings;
  newSettings.calibrationZero = _settings.calibrationZero;
  for(int i = 0;i<Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT;i++)
  {
    newSettings.calibrationMV[i] = _settings.calibrationMV[i];
    newSettings.calibrationMeasured[i] = _settings.calibrationMeasured[i];
    newSettings.calibrationScaler[i] = _settings.calibrationScaler[i];
  }
  return newSettings;
}

void Q2Balance::setCalibration(BalanceCalibrationStruct newSettings){
  _settings.calibrationZero = newSettings.calibrationZero;
  for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
  {
    _settings.calibrationMV[i] = newSettings.calibrationMV[i];
    _settings.calibrationMeasured[i] = newSettings.calibrationMeasured[i];
    _settings.calibrationScaler[i] = newSettings.calibrationScaler[i];
  }
}

void Q2Balance::tick(){
  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (_settling){
    if (_smoothValue < _settleMinVal){
      _settleMinVal = _smoothValue;
    }
    if (_smoothValue > _settleMaxVal){
      _settleMaxVal = _smoothValue;
    }
    _jitter = _settleMaxVal - _settleMinVal;
    if (now > _settleTimeout){
      _settling = false;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  if(_taring){
    _taring = false;
    _tared = true;
    _smoothValue = _rawValue;
    _tareValue = _rawValue;
    if (_afterCalibrated!=NULL){
      (*_afterCalibrated)();
      _afterCalibrated = NULL;
    }
  }

  if (_tared && abs(_smoothValue - _tareValue) > TARELIMIT){
    _tared = false;
  }

  if (_calibratingZero) {
    _settings.calibrationZero = _smoothValue;

    for(int i = 0;i<Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT;i++) // Recalc calibrations if zero changed
    {
      if(_settings.calibrationScaler[i] != 0){
        float delta = (float)(_settings.calibrationMV[i] - _settings.calibrationZero);
        float scaler = (float)_settings.calibrationMeasured[i] / delta;
        _settings.calibrationScaler[i] =  scaler;
      }
    }

    _calibratingZero = false;
    _calibrating = false;

    if (_afterCalibrated!=NULL){
      (*_afterCalibrated)();
      _afterCalibrated = NULL;
    }

  }

  if (_calibrating) {
    _calibrating = false;
    _settings.calibrationMV[_calibrationIndex] = _smoothValue;
    float delta = (float)(_smoothValue - _settings.calibrationZero);
    float scaler = (float)_settings.calibrationMeasured[_calibrationIndex] / delta;

    _settings.calibrationScaler[_calibrationIndex] =  scaler;

    if (_afterCalibrated!=NULL){
      (*_afterCalibrated)();
      _afterCalibrated = NULL;
    }
  }
}

long Q2Balance::settle(long settleTime) {
  _settling = true;
  _settleMinVal = _smoothValue;
  _settleMaxVal = _smoothValue;
  _settleTimeout = millis() + settleTime;
}

bool Q2Balance::settling(){
  return _settling;
};

bool Q2Balance::calibrating(){
  return _calibrating;
};

void Q2Balance::tare(long settleTime, void (*afterTared)(void)){
  if (!_calibrating && !_settling){
    _taring = true;
    _afterCalibrated = afterTared;
    settle(settleTime);
  }
}

bool Q2Balance::taring(){
  return _taring;
};

bool Q2Balance::tared(){
  return _tared;
};

void Q2Balance::calibrateZero(long settleTime, void (*afterCalibrated)(void)){
  if (!_calibrating && !_settling){
    _afterCalibrated = afterCalibrated;
    _calibratingZero = true;
    _calibrating = true;
    settle(settleTime);
  }
}

void Q2Balance::calibrate(int index, long measurement, long settleTime, void (*afterCalibrated)(void)){
  if (!_calibrating && !_settling){
    if (index < Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT){
      _afterCalibrated = afterCalibrated;
      _calibrating = true;
      _calibrationIndex = index;
      _settings.calibrationMeasured[index] = measurement;
      settle(settleTime);
    }
  }
}

void Q2Balance::measure(long measurement){
  long avg = _smoothValue;
  _rawValue = measurement;
  if (abs(measurement-_smoothValue) > JUMPLIMIT){  // If there is a large jump, abandon smoothing and set the value.
    _smoothValue = measurement;
    return;
  }
  avg -= avg / SAMPLE_COUNT;
  avg += measurement / SAMPLE_COUNT;
  _smoothValue = avg;
};

long Q2Balance::smoothValue(){
  return _smoothValue;
};

long Q2Balance::rawValue(){
  return _rawValue;
};

long Q2Balance::jitter(){
  return _jitter;
}

float Q2Balance::calcValue(int units, long value){
  if(_settings.calibrationZero == 0){
    return 0; //unzeroed
  }

  int index = findCalibrationWindow(_smoothValue);

  if (index == -1){
    return 0; //uncalibrated
  }
  long val = _smoothValue - _tareValue;
  if (_tared){
    return (0);
  }

  float scaled = round(val * _settings.calibrationScaler[index] * 100.0)/100.0;

  if (units > 0){

    switch (units) {
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_POUND:
      scaled = scaled * 0.002204622;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_OUNCE:
      scaled = scaled * 0.0352734;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_GRAIN:
      scaled = scaled * 15.43;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_TROY:
      scaled = scaled * 0.032;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_PWT:
      scaled = scaled * 0.643;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_CARAT:
      scaled = scaled * 5;
      break;
    case Q2BALANCE_UNIT_NEWTON:
      scaled = scaled * 0.009;
      break;
    }
  }

  return scaled;

}

float Q2Balance::adjustedValue(int units){
  return calcValue(_smoothValue, units);
}

float Q2Balance::adjustedRawValue(int units){
  return calcValue(_rawValue, units);
}

void Q2Balance::printCalibrations(){
  char buffer[128];
  sprintf(buffer, "ZERO %ld ",_settings.calibrationZero);
  Serial.println(buffer);
  for(int c=0;c<Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT;c++){
    printCalibration(c);
  }
}

void Q2Balance::printCalibration(int index){
  char buffer[128];
  char str_scaler[16];
  dtostrf(_settings.calibrationScaler[index], 6, 6, str_scaler);
  sprintf(buffer, "IDX %dMV %ld M %ld SC %s",
    index,
    _settings.calibrationMV[index],
    _settings.calibrationMeasured[index],
    str_scaler
  );
  Serial.println(buffer);
}

int Q2Balance::findCalibrationWindow(long voltage){
  int i,t=0;
  for (i = 0; i < Q2BALANCE_MARKER_COUNT; i++)
  {
    if (_settings.calibrationMV[i] == 0){
      break;
    }
    if (_settings.calibrationMV[i] >= voltage){
      break;
    }
    t = i;
  }
  if (_settings.calibrationMV[t] == 0){
    return -1;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: The purpose is to provide a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

When the library function `balance.tare` completes, it will invoke your own function (aka *callback function*), which you provide to function `balance.tare` within that additional input argument.

You can think of this callback-mechanism concept as "call me when you're done".

---

There are generally two ways to implement a callback-mechanism:

**Static Linkage:**

Function `balance.tare` invokes a function with a predefined (hard-coded) name.

You must implement a function of that name in your code.

Since the function-call and the function itself are necessarily located in different source files, the compiler has to assume that such function exists somewhere in the code, and leaves the address resolution to the linker (which will eventually replace it with a jump to the address of your function).

**Dynamic Linkage:**

Function `balance.tare` takes a function pointer as input, and invokes that function via the pointer (i.e., pushes input arguments if needed and jumps to the pointed function).

There is no symbol resolution at all - neither during compilation nor during linkage (you could say that the function-call is "resolved" during runtime).

This allows you to have function `balance.tare` invoking a different function every time you call it.

The only downside is perhaps an additional memory-read operation of the input argument which stores the address of your function, required in order to jump to that function.

This, instead of jumping to an already-known (constant) address.

But it is really platform-dependent, i.e., some HW architectures may execute this within a single instruction (just as any other function-call).

---

In your case, the library owner chose the latter.

Usage example:

```
void MyAfterTaredCallbackFunction(void)
{
    // Do some stuff
}

int main()
{
    ...
    balance.tare(100, MyAfterTaredCallbackFunction);
    ...
}
```